# Cannot Load Graph using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am using highcharts to display the graph dynamically . But my graph is not loaded . It throws the following error .

```
Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14
```

I am trying the following code . In this code i passing the series data in the variables  left and right . But my Graph is not loading . If i pass the variables as static Graph is Loaded.

```
    var left = [];
   var right = [];

 if(($('#love').val() != '') && ($('#architectural').val() != '')){


 var rights = [[  $('#love').val() , $('#love').val() ] ,      [$('#architectural').val() ,$('#architectural').val() ]];

}


if(($('#righty').val() != '') && ($('#lefty').val() != '')){

if($('#righty').val() == 5){

   var second1 = (1 +','+ $('#right1').val() );  

}else if($('#righty').val() == 4 ){

    var second1 = (2 +','+ $('#right1').val());  


}else if($('#righty').val() == 3 ){

   var second1 = (3 +','+ $('#right1').val());  

 }else if($('#righty').val() == 2 ){

   var second1 = (4 +','+ $('#right1').val());  

 }else{

    var second1 = (5 +','+ $('#right1').val());  

 }


 if($('#lefty').val() == 5){

  var first1 = ( $('#condition').val() +','+ 1 );  

  }else if($('#lefty').val() == 4 ){

  var first1 = ($('#condition').val() +','+ 2);  

}else if($('#lefty').val() == 3 ){

  var first1 = ($('#condition').val() +','+ 3);  

}else if($('#lefty').val() == 2 ){

 var first1 = ($('#condition').val() +','+ 4);  

}else{

 var first1 = ($('#condition').val() +','+ 5);  

}


var lefts = [[  second1 ] , [ first1 ] ];

 }

 //var left = [[4,7],[9,2]];
 //var right = [[2,2],[4,4]];

     left.push(lefts);
      right.push(rights);

  Highcharts.chart('container', {

 title:{
    text:''
 },

 tooltip: { enabled: false },      

 exporting: { enabled: false },

 credits: {enabled: false},


 plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 1
    }
 },

xAxis: {
    max: 10,
    min: 1,
    tickInterval: 1
},

 yAxis: {
    max: 10,
    min: 1,
    tickInterval: 1,

  plotLines: [{
  color: 'black', 
  value: 5.5,
  width: 2

  }],

},

  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: left
  },
 {
   showInLegend: false,
    data: right
  }],
 });

      }           

  }
```

I am getting the following  graph :

[image]

Comment: check this link www.highcharts.com/errors/14, you are creating string not array, you have to use `foo.push()` where `foo` is javascript array

Comment: how to push this into series data

Comment: i declare left as array and right as array . and i use left.push(lefts);   right.push(rights); but again map is not loaded

Comment: can you add fiddle example

Comment: ya sure . i will send

Comment: Sorry some reason i cannot share it as fiddle. I  will send my code again

Comment: So what is the output of your `left` and `right` variables? Also, you're showing us your graph, but not explaining what's wrong with it. What are you expecting the graph to show?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what your code is supposed to be doing. This: `var second1 = (1 +','+ $('#right1').val() )` is building a string, not an array of values, for instance, which isn't going to work (like @Deep3015 mentioned, you need to use `push()` to build your array)

Comment: My left and right var values are  var left = [[4,7],[9,2]]; 
/var right = [[2,2],[4,4]];       also  i push my var into array . plese check the question again @ jlbriggs

Comment: Right. But you're pushing a string into that array: `var second1 = (5 +','+ $('#right1').val())`. The `5 +','+` makes the value a string with a comma in it, not an array. You need to use `push()` to build those first arrays. Unless I am missing something. Figure out how to get this into a fiddle or other live demo for best results here.

Comment: If i use  var second1 = (5 , $('#right1').val()); means also having no graph. i cannot share the fiddle details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i changed my string values passing in the variable left and right. here is my correct answer,

```
 if(($('#love').val() != '') && ($('#architectural').val() != '')){


 var right= [[  parseFloat($('#love').val()) , parseFloat($('#love').val()) ] , [ (parseFloat($('#architectural').val())),parseFloat($('#architectural').val())]];

   }


   if(($('#righty').val() != '') && ($('#lefty').val() != '')){

   if($('#righty').val() == 5){

    var second1 = [1 , parseFloat($('#right1').val()) ];  

   }else if($('#righty').val() == 4 ){

       var second1 = [2 , parseFloat($('#right1').val())];  


   }else if($('#righty').val() == 3 ){

       var second1 = [3 , parseFloat($('#right1').val())];  

   }else if($('#righty').val() == 2 ){

     var second1 = [4 , parseFloat($('#right1').val())];  

   }else{

      var second1 = [5 , parseFloat($('#right1').val())];  

   }


  if($('#lefty').val() == 5){

     var first1 = [parseFloat($('#condition').val()) , 1 ];  

  }else if($('#lefty').val() == 4 ){

      var first1 = [parseFloat($('#condition').val()) , 2];  

  }else if($('#lefty').val() == 3 ){

       var first1 = [parseFloat($('#condition').val()) , 3];  

  }else if($('#lefty').val() == 2 ){

       var first1 = [parseFloat($('#condition').val()) , 4];  

  }else{

    var first1 = [parseFloat($('#condition').val()) , 5];  

  }


  var left = [second1   ,  first1  ];

 }






     Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title:{
        text:''
     },

     tooltip: { enabled: false },      

     exporting: { enabled: false },

     credits: {enabled: false},


      plotOptions: {
        series: {
        pointStart: 1
           }
     },

     xAxis: {
         max: 10,
         min: 1,
         tickInterval: 1
     },

    yAxis: {
        max: 10,
        min: 1,
        tickInterval: 1,

    plotLines: [{
     color: 'black', 
     value: 5.5,
     width: 2

    }],

  },

  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: left
   },
   {
     showInLegend: false,
    data: right
   }],
   });

     }           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the issue is use strings instead of numbers.

Use

```
parseFloat($('#love').val())
```

instead of

```
$('#love').val()
```

and all other `val()`

Comment: Sorry it is not working .I add parseFloar()  in all .val() . but Not working . Can you share any fiddle way

Comment: I can update your code, but currently I do not have a knowledge how your code does it look like. So please supply me the live demo of current chart (you can contact with us also by email, check the http://highcharts.com/support) if project is protected and you would like to avoid share public access.